# Dell Latitude E7450 webcam doesn't work w/ 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, webcam

I'm new to Linux (forced myself to learn by installing it), but have about 20 years in Windows.

I got a used Dell Latitude E7450 with Windows and wiped it out, then installed Ubuntu 18.04. Most stuff works correctly but the integrated webcam doesn't: when I open Skype and check video, the led powers on, but no image shows up. Cheese shows blank and options greyed out.

hardinfo output shows an "Input device" identified as "SPCA2082 PC CAMERA".

Can you please assist on where should I look? I checked the Dell support site, but there's no specific Ubuntu driver for anything but the BIOS.  Thanks very much in advance.

Below are some outputs from `lsusb` & `lspci`

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2082 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 2a70:4ee7  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

````
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 59)```
````

Comment: FYI, your webcam is device `1bcf:2082`. I have an E7450 as well, but my webcam is device `1bcf:2b8c`. It is recognized and grabbed by the `uvcvideo` driver as reported by `dmesg` (and it works fine). Perhaps this issue is the same as yours? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1062331/integrated-webcam-not-working-after-upgrade-to-18-04 ... Unfortunately it magically started working for that user. Try installing and running `cheese` as root to see if it's a permissions issue.